# How to eliminate a substring from a specific string

Tags: javascript

I am having a string like below:

```
The combination is excluded by the following restriction\nRestriction number 16. --No-name--If-Then---- [Check the description here].
```

I want to print this complete text, except `Restriction number 16.` I want to skip it, so that the resulting restriction will look like this:

```
The combination is excluded by the following restriction\n --No-name--If-Then---- [Check the description here].
```

I have tried using various methods, like using replace and split, but nothing is working perfectly for me.

The complexity here is the text `Restriction number` is always fixed, but the numeric value next to it i.e., `16` can change every time. It can be anything.

So every time we have to replace the complete text `Restriction number followed by a number` with empty space character.

Comment: you need a regular expression: `.replace(/Restriction number [0-9]+\./, '')`

Comment: @georg This is probably the best answer

Comment: Thank you @georg. This is the best answer, works perfectly as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here goes. Slice the original string in the correct positions to find the dynamic number. Then replace that value from the original string. Like so:

```
let myString = "The combination is excluded by the following restriction\nRestriction number 16. --No-name--If-Then---- [Check the description here]."

let i = myString.indexOf("Restriction number ") + "Restriction number ".length

let s2 = myString.substr(i)
let dynamicNumber = s2.substr(0, s2.indexOf(' '))

let stringToReplace = "Restriction number " + dynamicNumber

let finalString = myString.replace(stringToReplace, "")
```

Comment: Here, problem is that numeric value after Restriction number is not fixed everytime. It can change. So we have to replace Restriction number + dynamic numeric value with empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to replace substring with empty string ("").
It can be done using `.replace()` method, and the syntax is as shown:

`string.replace(substring, "");`

OR just,

`string.replace(substring);`

Because if you don't pass anything in the second argument, it will automatically consider it as an empty string.

```js
let str = "The combination is excluded by the following restriction\nRestriction number 16. --No-name--If-Then---- [Check the description here].";

console.log(str.replace("Restriction number 16.", ""));
```

Answer (score -1):

this work well

```
console.log("The combination is excluded by the following restriction\nRestriction number 16. --No-name--If-Then---- [Check the description here].".replace("Restriction number 16.",""))
```

use it as:

```
"your string".replace("your replace string","")
```